# Error reading in text file with strings and integers into an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, text-files, java.util.scanner, ioexception

I'm getting an input mismatch exception when scanning in data from a text file i created that contains both strings and numbers.

I put a try-catch statement to try and better understand the error, just ignore it.

My driver class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookShelf {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("./src/Books.txt"));
    ArrayList<Books> books = new ArrayList<Books>();

    String author, title, publisher;
    int copyright;
    int count =0;

    try {
    while(scan.hasNext()){
        title = scan.nextLine();
        author = scan.nextLine();
        publisher = scan.nextLine();
        copyright = scan.nextInt();

        Books book = new Books(title,author,publisher,copyright);
        books.add(book);

    }
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }


    while (count <books.size() ){
        System.out.println(books.get(count));
        count++;
    }
}
}
```

My Books constructor class:

```
public class Books {

private String title, author, publisher;
private int copyright;

public Books(String newTitle, String newAuthor, String newPub, int newCopy ){
title = newTitle;
author = newAuthor;
publisher = newPub;
copyright = newCopy;
}
// Setters
public void setTitle(String newTitle){
    title = newTitle;
}
public void setAuthor(String newAuthor){
    author = newAuthor;
}
public void setPublisher(String newPub){
    publisher = newPub;
}
public void setCopyrightDate(int newCopy){
    copyright = newCopy;
}

// Getters
public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}
public String getAuthor(){
    return author;
}
public String getPublisher(){
    return publisher;
}
public int getCopyrightDate(){
    return copyright;
}
public String toString(){
    String result ="";
    result ="Title: "+title +"\nAuthor: "+author+"\nPublisher: "+ publisher;
    result += "\nCopyright Date: "+copyright;
    return result;
}



}
```

And my text file:

```
Java Software Solutions
Lewis & Loftus
Addison-Wesley
2012
Faces in Time
Lewis Aleman
Megalodon Entertainment
2012
Purple Cow
Seth Godin
Portfolio
2002
```

From the order of my text file and the data types in my while loop I'm having trouble understanding why my code has an input mismatch.

Comment: after this line 'copyright = scan.nextInt()' just add the following -> if(scan.hasNext())scan.next(); That should do it. Thanks

Comment: thanks Aritra, before seeing your comment I changed the line to: 'copyright = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());' after looking through some other pages and it worked the way I wanted

Comment: Ok thanks :-) Glad it worked out for you.